# How to use renaudcerrato's FloatingSearchView with ArrayList<Strting>?

Tags: android, arraylist, searchview, floating

I tried using the sample app of this FloatingSearchView and it was working fine. But I couldn't understand how can I use it with ArrayList

Please give a sample code if anyone can.

Link of Library
https://github.com/renaudcerrato/FloatingSearchView

Thank You

Comment: What do You want not clear from question, explain clearly so we can help you

Comment: @USKMobility When we type something on FloatingSearchView, it gives us suggestions. I am having an ArrayList<String> and I want FloatingSearchView to filter from the ArrayList<String>